# Water hammer noises on some irrigation zones

Tags: water-pressure

The regular water pressure in my home is 55 psi.
My home is three years old and the irrigation system is two years old.

I have a 9 zone irrigation system. Recently, I began hearing water hammer sounds every 30-45 seconds on 5 of those 9 zones.

When I went downstairs and looked at the water pressure, I could see that when the zones that make the hammer noise are running, the water pressure would start to rise, hit 60 psi, make a sound, and the water pressure would start to drop. When it hit 40 psi, it would make the loud hammer sound and the pressure will begin to slowly rise again. It will rise back up to 60, make the noise, drop to 40 psi and make the hammer noise and repeat as long as that zone is on.

The zones that do not cause this issue keep a steady water pressure of 58 psi.
It should also be noted that this issue only happens when the sprinklers are on. There is no other hammer sounds otherwise.

I cannot figure this issue out and I’m not sure if it’s a well issue, a plumbing issue or a sprinkler issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to increase the pressure on the pressure control valve

Comment: you have a prv lowering pressure to irrigation to approximately 30 psi or running it with house pressure?